# why my image is not animating

Tags: jquery, html, css

![background.png][1]
![card.png][2]
want to show this card.png in button and background image will be moving on mouseover and mouse out .

```
 <style type="text/css">
    #tb_whisper {
     background-image:url("background.png") !important;
    }
    .tb_send {
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #000000 0%, #B8B6B6 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border:1px solid red;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    height:28px;
    margin-right:4px;
    }
    .ui-corner-all {
    -moz-border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px !important;
    }
    .toolbar {
    -moz-border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #000000 0%, #B8B6B6 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height:28px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:4px 0;
    }
    .tb_nav {
    border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    height:28px;
    margin-right:4px;
    width:28px;
    }
    button::-moz-focus-inner {
        border:0;
        padding-top:0;
    }




    </style>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script  type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tb_nav')
     .mouseover(function(){
      $(this).animate(
       {'backgroundPosition':"(-36px 0px)"}, 
       {'duration':500});
     })
     .mouseout(function(){
      if(!$(this).hasClass('tb_nav_active')) {
       $(this).animate(
        {'backgroundPosition':"(0 0)"}, 
        {'duration':500});
      }
     }); 

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button style="background-position: 0px 0px;" id="tb_whisper" title="Whisper" class="tb_nav ui-corner-all">
    </button></html>![alt text][3]


  [backgrund]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEbd4.png
  [card ]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/So7Re.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/18jx0.pn
```

g

Comment: change the sytanx it should work ,,, i gave the answer first...just kidding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css + animation syntax is wrong. try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.tb_nav')
    .mouseover(function(){
          $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "-36px 0"}, 500);
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('tb_nav_active')) {
            $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "0 0"}, 500);
        }
    }); 

});
```

Comment: now background is moving that is fine but i want this card . png to remain fix on this button , how i can to this ?

Comment: {'duration':500} can't we can give like this it is running in my code ?

Comment: That would also work ref http://jsfiddle.net/tKgy9/. I was trying to minimize code.

Comment: cool now i got the problem was () in backgroundPosition , please fix the second card image on button .

Answer (score 1):

looks like your syntax is wroing for background position try this syntax

```
   ('background-position', '0px 0px');
```

I just gave example,  use your own co-ordinates

try like this it will work

```
.animate({backgroundPosition: '500px 150px'})
```

Comment: what you  want to say i am not getting please explain

Comment: what i need to change and where please advise this ?